# Why don't null Mock objects throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
public void someMethod(ObjectA a) {
    ObjectB b = a.getB();
    b.doSomething();
}
```

and my test is:

```
@Test
public void someTest_1() {
    when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
    ...
    mockB = null;

    someMethod(mockA);
}
```

Shouldn't the above code throw an NPE?

When I change my test to:

```
@Test
public void someTest_2() {
    when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(null);

    someMethod(mockA);
}
```

then my code correctly throws a null pointer exception.

What is the difference between the first and second versions of my test?

In my first version, I'm telling mockA to return mockB. But I'm also setting mockB to be null, so when b.doSomething() is called, I think that that method should throw a null pointer since it is trying to invoke null.doSomething().

I get that I should go with the second version for the behavior that I'm trying to test, but I don't know why the first version has different behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With :

```
when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
...
mockB = null;
```

The `thenReturn` sets the mock to return the value that mockB was holding at THAT moment (ie, the moment that the `when ... thenReturn` was executed), regardless of what happens to mockB subsequently.

It's not so different to how Strings behave :

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = s1;
s1 = "xyz";
```

The result here is that s2 still has the value "abc", since that was the value at that moment it was assigned, regardless of what happens to s1 subsequently.

**EDIT:**

The way to think about this is that the variables like `mockB`, `s1` and `s2` are "reference" (aka "pointer") variables - that is, their value points to the address in memory of the target object.

When `thenReturn(mockB)` or `s2 = s1` are executed, it is the **value** of `mockB` and `s1` that is being passed or copied - that is, the address of the target object-or-string (not the address of the variables `mockB` or `s1` themselves).  This is why subsequent changes to the values of of the variables `mockB` or `s1` themselves has no effect.

Where the positioning of the `when ... then` has no effect is in the actions performed on the object itself - for example :

```
when(mockB.getName()).thenReturn("fred");

when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);

when(mockB.getAge()).thenReturn(23);
...
mockB = null
```

The positioning of the `when(mockA.getB())` does not affect (and is not affected by) the setting up of `getName` and `getAge` of the mock object, since those operations do not change the address of that object in memory.

Comment: wow, thanks for the string example. that really puts things in perspective... i was under the impression that since the `thenReturn` is referencing an object, the order in which i place the `when...then`s didn't matter... though i still think that the first method makes more intuitive sense

Comment: Glad it helped;  I've just added to the answer to (hopefully) clarify what's happening, so with the right ideas it becomes more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

In first test case you are mocking a dummy object,so mocikto does not report you null of mockB.

In second test case you are explicitly putting the code to return null.